# Insert into Many to Many Table - Node JS MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to figure out how to do a mySQL query to insert data via a form to different tables via a post request (many to many relationship.) My tables are as follows -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xTkd.jpg

I'm really struggling to figure out a mySQL statement to join the Pokemon & Location table to create a new Pokemon at a certain location. Any ideas?

```
    router.post('/', function(req, res){
            var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
            var sql = "INSERT INTO pokemon (pokemonname, evolutionlevel) VALUES(?,?)";
            var sql2 = "INSERT INTO location (locationname) VALUES(?, ?)";
            var inserts = [req.body.pokemonname, req.body.evolutionlevel, req.body.locationname];
            sql = mysql.pool.query(sql, sql2, inserts, function(error, results, fields){
                    if(error){
                            res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                                    res.end();
                    } else{
                            res.redirect('/location');
                    }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to join tables for insert. You can do it in two different statements as below

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
    var sql = "INSERT INTO pokemon (pokemonname, evolutionlevel) VALUES(?,?)";
    var sql2 = "INSERT INTO location (locationname) VALUES(?, ?)";
    var insert1 = [req.body.pokemonname, req.body.evolutionlevel];
    var insert2 = [req.body.locationname];
    var first_sql = mysql.pool.query(sql, insert1, function(error, results, fields){
        if(error){
                res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                        res.end();
        } else {
            var second_sql = mysql.pool.query(sql2, insert2, function(error, results, fields){
                if(error){
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                    res.end();
                }
            });
            res.redirect('/location');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: pool.query() may not use the same connection. It can use different connection. So as per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections), it is better to use a single connection by using pool.getConnection() and then do your queries and finally release that connection by connection.release().